# difference between 2 variables in c ( char line[LINE_SIZE]; ) and (char *result) in this program

Tags: c

A very simple c program which reads from a file and outputs on terminal.
What is the difference between result and line here?
For example if I print (result) or (line) inside the while loop the output of both is same.

```
printf("%s", line);
printf("%s", result);
```

but inside the condition of while loop if I replace

```
while(result !=NULL)
```

with

```
while(line != NULL)
```

it does not stop.
source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int LINE_SIZE = 1000;

  FILE *infile;
  char *result;

  char line[LINE_SIZE];

  infile = fopen("in.txt", "r");
  result = fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, infile);
  while(result != NULL)
    {
      //printf("%s", line);
      printf("%s", result);
      result = fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, infile);

    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(line != NULL)
```

*line* is an array. If you just write *line*, it will **always** return a pointer to its first element (here, a character). Therefore the condition above will be always true.

The *fgets* function returns your data pointer on success, NULL on failure (e.g when the end of file has been reached and it couldn't read any character).

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` On success, the function returns `string`.
If end of file (`EOF`) is found, the pointer returned is a `null pointer` (so your pointer `result` will become `null`) and the contents of `string` remain unchanged ( in your case `line` remains unchanged).

Hence

```
while(line != NULL)
```

will continue to execute since line remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

char line[LINE_SIZE], line is an array name, it's a constant, never to be null, if you write line = fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, infile);, it will tell an error! fgets() changes line[0], line[1], line[2]... not line.